# Writing BigQuery table: GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found

Tags: azure, pyspark, google-bigquery, databricks

I need to save a PySpark DataFrame into a BigQuery table from my Azure Databricks notebook.  I can read data from BigQuery, and I've been able to create an empty table with the schema I defined, as shown below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        <<path_to_my_credentials_file.json>>,
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
    )

google_project = "test_project"
google_dataset = "test_dataset"
table_name = "test_table"
target_table = f"{google_project}.{google_dataset}.{table_name}"
temporary_bucket = "test_temporary_bucket"

# Create client
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=google_project,)

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("column1", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("column2", "STRING"),
]

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("google.cloud.auth.client.id", <<client_id>>)

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email", credentials.service_account_email)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.project.id", google_project)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id", <<private_key_id>>)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key", <<private_key>>)

# Create table
bigquery_table = client.create_table(bigquery.Table(target_table, schema=schema))
```

As I said, I can read it and it's an empty table with the correct schema as I would expect:

```
read_df = (
    spark.read.format("bigquery")
    .option("credentials", encrypted_credentials_to_provide)
    .option("table", table_id)
    .option("project", google_project)
    .option("parentProject", google_project)
    .option("viewsEnabled", "true")
    .load()
)

read_df.display()
read_df.printSchema()
```

The problem comes when I try to write data into this table:

```
(
    final_df.write.format("bigquery") 
    .mode("overwrite")
    .option("credentialsFile", <<path_to_my_credentials_file.json>>)
    .option("parentProject", google_project)
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket", f"{temporary_bucket}") # I've tried f"gs://{temporary_bucket}"
    .option("table", target_table)
    .save()
)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o782.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.<init>(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:63)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.insert(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:469)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Do I need to install something in the cluster? Am I missing additional parameters when writing? Do I need to set the SparkSession in a different way?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank in advance!